# What does 'i' mean in Latin

Tags: vocabulary

I was reading a story in Latin, and part of it said "i nunc, Mercuri". I don't know what i is in Latin. By the way, this line is said in dialogue. Is it a filler word similar to the "umm" or does it mean something else? I am really confused. Thank you for all the help! I also tried looking it up, but I didn't find any good results. What does it mean? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, M. C. If this answer is now solved, don't forget to click the check to mark it so. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 9):

*Ī* is the imperative singular of *eō, īre*, "to go". So *ī* on its own means "go!" (as a command to a single person). In this case, the character is saying "go now, Mercurius".

The other one-letter words in Latin (that I know of) are *ā* ("away from"), *ē* ("out of"), and *ō* (used to address someone). As far as I know, **ū* is not a word.

Comment: Also, it seems that no short vowel makes a word on its own.