# How many letters are words in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, alphabet, homonyms

In English, there are a few words that sound the same as a single letter. Some are spelled with a single letter ("I", "a") while others are just pronounced that way ("eye", "cue", "why").

How many of these words exist in Latin? [I mentioned a few in another answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/8999/406), but already off the top of my head I can think of more once we allow consonants. I'm curious how full of an alphabet one can make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based on [this question and answer concerning the classical names of the letters](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/732/79).
Given the pronunciation of a Latin word, there is typically a unique spelling (unlike in English!) so the exercise is pretty straightforward.

Yes:

- ā: preposition
- dē: preposition
- ē: preposition
- ī: imperative of *ire*
- ō: interjection
- ĕs: form of *esse*
- tē: form of *te*
- ĕx or ĭx: preposition (*ex*)

No (with near hits):

- bē: noun *bes*, forms of *beare*
- cē: imperative *cie*
- ĕf: Perhaps one could argue that *ex* is pronounced as *ef* before a word starting with *f*, as in compounds we have *efficere* and others.
- gē: One might Latinize the name of the Greek goddess as *Ge*, but I have never encountered it or even *Gaea*. One would expect *Terra* or *Tellus* in this use.
- hā: If one argues that the initial *h-* is not pronounced, then this sounds like the preposition. But that would draw the very name of this letter into question. As cmw points out in a comment, this is [used in Plautus for laughter](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/119/16/12/3096-3100,3100-3103@1#12), but it can also be seen as a part of a longer word *hahae* or similar, and the *a* is short.
- cā: —
- ĕl: —
- ĕm: This looks it could be an accusative for of *is*, but it is not.
- ĕn: interjection *ēn*
- pē: noun *pes*
- cū: pronoun *cui*
- ĕr: forms of *esse*, nouns *era* and *erus*
- ū: —
- y ([ī]) graeca: —
- zēta: —

There seem to be eight letters that are words.

As Draconis points out in a comment, some letters have alternate names (*esse, elle, emme*…).
These do not seem to bring any new letters to the list, but S gets a new word in *esse*.
This also produces the close hit *ille ≈ elle*.

Comment: How about .i. .v. .x. etc pronounced *unus -a -um; quinque, decem.* And i◦  v◦  x◦ *primo, quinto, decimo.*  Another category which might deserve inclusion are Caius *G* Lucius *L* and Marcus *M.*

Comment: @Hugh Hmm... I would consider those to be abbreviations. If I understood correctly, the question was about words that sound like the names of the letters. Abbreviations seem to be pretty far from the examples given in the question.

Comment: From Plautus: [*Há ha hae.*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/119/16/12/3096-3100,3100-3103@1#12)

Comment: @cmw Good find! I moved it to the other category.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I should have been clearer, though. So [Lewis and Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dhahae!) print it as one word, though *hahae* is also attested. Also, it's short, and if that post is accurate then the word for H has a long A, so not quite a match. I'd keep it in the "close but no cigar" category, but replace the part about the silent H with the above info.

Comment: @cmw I should have read more carefully.I updated again, moving it to the second category. It is an interesting addition to the list!